# How to clear the cache after user log out from website in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session, caching, logout

I would like to clear the cache after user logged out of particular session. I don't want anonymous user to use back button of the browser to see the cached pages which has confidential data.

At the same time i don't want to clear the cache during valid session to avoid performance hit.

What is the best practice to handle this scenario?

Comment: This might be the good way to do it : http://www.webtuts.in/how-to-disable-browser-cache-easily-in-codeigniter/

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola, I don't want to get rid of cache during valid session.Is there a way i can clear cache after logout?

Comment: As mention in tutorial place `$this->output->nocache();` in your logout action.

Answer (score 0):

After destroying the session use

```
$this->cache->clean();
```

for details
check [this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/caching.html) out

Comment: I have implemented in my library after logout. Still i am able to see the history of pages using back button.
      
$this->CI->load->driver('cache');
$this->CI->cache->clean();